# Are there constraints on which npm version I can use based on my node version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

Is there any way to know if I can use a specific version of npm with a specific version of node?

I want to use latest npm (6.4.1 at the time of writing) with latest LTS (8.11.4 at time of writing).

I realise that the versions are pretty close that there might not be a problem but I have learned not to make assumptions about stuff I don't know :P

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you install **nvm** (https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md) and let it do the version management.

**Usage:**
To download, compile, and install the latest release of node, do this:

```
nvm install node
```

And then in any new shell just use the installed version:

```
nvm use node
```

Or you can just run it:

```
nvm run node --version
```

Or, you can run any arbitrary command in a subshell with the desired version of node:

```
nvm exec 4.2 node --version
```

You can also get the path to the executable to where it was installed:

```
nvm which 5.0
```

Read more: [Managing Node.js Versions with nvm](https://davidwalsh.name/nvm)

Comment: Thank you. I am already using nvm. It's just that until v10 becomes LTS for production we are using v8 and I like some of the features of the latest npm versions.

Comment: You can use `npm i npm@latest` to update the npm to latest version.

Comment: Yeah, but my question was about being okay to install any version of npm with any version of node

Comment: No, you must check the change log for that.